# json parsing in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

Here is my Json

```
{
    "id": "63",
    "name": "Magnet",
    "price": "₹1250",
    "description": "",
    "image": [
        "catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0012_azw1e3ge.jpg",
        "catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0029_6mr3ndda.jpg",
        "catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0028_ooc2ea52.jpg",
        "catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0026_4wjz5882.jpg",
        "catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0024_e38xvczi.jpg",
        "catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0020_vyzhfkvf.jpg",
        "catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0018_u686bmde.jpg",
        "catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0016_c8ffp19i.jpg"
    ],
    "thumb_image": [
        "cache/catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0012_azw1e3ge-300x412.jpg",
        "cache/catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0029_6mr3ndda-300x412.jpg",
        "cache/catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0028_ooc2ea52-300x412.jpg",
        "cache/catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0026_4wjz5882-300x412.jpg",
        "cache/catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0024_e38xvczi-300x412.jpg",
        "cache/catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0020_vyzhfkvf-300x412.jpg",
        "cache/catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0018_u686bmde-300x412.jpg",
        "cache/catalog/IMG-20150119-WA0016_c8ffp19i-300x412.jpg"
    ],
    "specifications": [
        {
            "Fabrics": [
                "Pure chiffon straight cut suits 48&quot; length"
            ]
        },
        {
            "MOQ": [
                "Minimum 10"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In above json string the "specification" arraylist has dynamic number of key and each key has dynamic number of values

So how can parse this? Please help if anyone knows this...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do parsing. In your case `specifications` should be an array, so you'll be able to loop on each items.

You might want to :

- Create your own JSON parse class / methods ;
- Use an existing *library* to parse JSON.

For the second option, you can give a look at the following :
https://github.com/Wolg/awesome-swift#jsonxml-manipulation

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourJson = data as? NSDictionary

if let id = yourJson.valueForKey("id") as String
{
      //save your id from json
}
if let name = yourJson.valueForKey("name") as String
{
     //save your name
}
...

if let images = yourJson.valueForKey("image") as NSArray
{
     for im in images
     {
         //save image
     }
     //the same for all othe images
}
```

... And so on...

You should also watch some tutorials, to understand the basics of JSON parsing..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtcscjMxxq4